# Want to make a Call in Android through one Particular Medium

Tags: android, makefile, call

I want to create a Call Making Functionality in my App which I had done. But the Problem is that I have more than one sources to support the Call making like I have Viber in my device. Now what happens is that when I attempt to make a Call, it asks me to choose one to do so which I don't want.

Is there any way out by which I can make a Call directly by the Medium I want without me being asked to choosing one?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `android:priority` value inside the manifest. It describes in what order an Intent is delivered to its BroadcastReceiver. If you set the priority to a value more or equal to the Viber one, your BroadcastReceiver is run at first